# Eclipse debugger fails to run

Tags: java, eclipse, jdwp

I am trying to run a debugger in Eclipse but if fails to run, I get the following error:

> FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

windows 7

jdk 7

tried to reboot

I have tried modifying hosts file but nothing helped. Any other ideas?

ANSWER: Deleting Avast antivirus solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Avast will fix the issue in the next release (build 9.0.2008.177.)

For more info:
https://feedback.avast.com/responses/eclipse-debug-functionality-not-working-after-upgrade-to-avast-2014